# Sampling unsigned integers from 1D texture using integer texture coordinates

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, texture1d

I want to pass a big array of `unsigned short` tuples (rect geometries) to my Fragment Shader and be able to sample them as-is using integer texture coordinates, to do this I'm trying with a 1D texture as follows, but get just blank (0) values.

Texture creation and initialization:

```
GLushort data[128][2];
// omitted array initialization

GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexImage1D(
    GL_TEXTURE_1D,
    0,
    GL_RG16UI,
    128,
    0,
    GL_RG_INTEGER,
    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
    data
);
```

Texture passing to shader:

```
int tex_unit = 0;
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + tex_unit);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex);
glUniform1iv(loc, 1, &tex_unit);
```

Debug fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 out_color;

uniform usampler1D tex;

void main()
{
    uvec4 rect = texelFetch(tex, 70, 0);
    uint w = rect.r;
    uint h = rect.g;
    out_color = w > 0u ? vec4(1) : vec4(0);
}
```

Things that work for sure: non-zero data in `data` array, texture image unit setup and sampler uniform initialization.

OpenGL 4.1, OSX 10.11.6 "El Capitan"

Comment: As an arguable "proof" that the texture is created and sampled, the debug shader renders white colors if the texture image data is populated like this, with everything else untouched:

`glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RG, 128, 0, GL_RG, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, data);`

(although this makes little sense to me, because if I understood the documentation well, the `internalFormat` must match the sampler type, and in this case, the first is `float` and second is `unsigned int`)

Answer (score 1):

After some googling and by trial and error, I discovered [this post](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/183785-Integer-Texture-Filtering), which states that with integer texture formats (for example, `GL_RG16UI` internal format) `GL_LINEAR` filtering cannot be specified and only `GL_NEAREST` applies, thus, everything worked out with the following texture creation code:

```
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexImage1D(
    GL_TEXTURE_1D,
    0,
    GL_RG16UI,
    128,
    0,
    GL_RG_INTEGER,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    data
);
```